# Is possible to have PHP + MongoDb + Nginx in the same Dockerfile?

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I need to have the 3 services running into only one docker container. I have this "system" done in one docker-compose, but due to some limitations I need to have it into only one dockerfile. The application that I want to run is in PHP (with Symfony) + MongoDb.

Right now, I'm executing this command:

`sudo docker run -p 9091:80 -p 27017:27017 myapp`

And the maximum that I get is a 502 error when I browse to localhost:9091.

Thanks

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-stretch
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y \
    nginx \
    mongodb
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN pecl install mongodb
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mongodb

RUN service nginx start
RUN service mongodb start

EXPOSE 9091
EXPOSE 27017

COPY entrypoint.sh /
WORKDIR /usr/www
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

COPY . /usr/www
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e -u

service nginx start
service mongodb start

tail -f /dev/null
```

nginx.conf

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /usr/www/public;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        }

        error_log /dev/stderr debug;
        access_log /dev/stdout;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that PHP is not running inside your container, make a `docker exec` inside to verify that. The reason that this is happening is that you have overwritten the `entrypoint` of the image. Make sure that you start the php-fpm process inside your `entrypoint.sh` and that you have configure properly nginx.conf to proxy_pass to it's port or socket.

Comment: I just added the `nginx.conf` that I'm using. Also I just tried to add the php-fm (`php-fpm -F -R &` before `service nginx start`) to the `entrypoint.sh` without success (still the 502 error).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, but it is not the recommended approach in the context of docker.

> Limiting each container to one process is a good [rule of thumb](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/).

**Decouple applications**

Each container should have only one concern. Decoupling applications into multiple containers makes it easier to scale horizontally and reuse containers. For instance, a web application stack might consist of three separate containers, each with its own unique image, to manage the web application, database, and an in-memory cache in a decoupled manner.

So better to use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) and launch three container and use the docker network for communication.

It will less or more likely this

[image]

or using docker-compose

[image]

As far the issue in your current as mentioned in the comment you are not starting PHP, better to check logs of the container.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but to due to some limitations I only can use one docker file.

Comment: then you need to ```service nginx start
service mongodb start
php-fpm```
remove tail command

Comment: Still I have the 502 error: `Starting nginx: nginx.
Starting database: mongodb.
[12-Sep-2019 09:50:01] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 40
[12-Sep-2019 09:50:01] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
172.17.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2019:09:50:06 +0000] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: this `502` badgateway from nginx config. correct the `/etc/nginx..`

Comment: `docker exec -it yourcontianername bash` and "helloworld" to `/var/www/html/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your dockerfile is you are not starting php-fpm. You shall use supervisord to manage multiple services in a single container , [This](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) document explains this use case very clearly.

You can also refer [this](https://github.com/topix-hackademy/docker-nginx-ssh-mysql-php7/blob/master/supervisord.conf) example for the complete supervisord conf for nginx,php-fpm and mysql .

As a piece of opinion ,It is unadvisable to run multiple services in a single container .